# Mass density of radiation in Friedmann equation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, cosmology, pressure, space-expansion

$$\frac{{\ddot a}}{a} =  - \frac{{4\pi G}}{3}(\rho  + 3P) + \frac{\Lambda }{3}$$

In the case of matter, pressure $P=0$,

In the case of radiation, pressure $P=(1/3)ρ$,

In the case of cosmological constant, pressure $P=-ρ$.

When this goes into the Friedmann equation, does it have the following form?

**Considering only the case of radiation term**

$$\rho  + 3P = 0 + 3(\frac{1}{3}{\rho _r}) = {\rho _r}$$

Is it this form?

**The mass density of radiation = 0, and the pressure term of radiation $P=(1/3)ρ$**

$$\rho  + 3P = 0 + 3(\frac{1}{3}{\rho _r}) = {\rho _r}$$

Is this correct?

When we say that the energy density(or mass density) of radiation is ${\rho _r}$, which form is it in Friedmann equation?
$\rho  + 3P = {\rho _r} + 3(\frac{1}{3}{\rho _r}) = 2{\rho _r}$    or
$\rho  + 3P = 0 + 3(\frac{1}{3}{\rho _r}) = {\rho _r}$

Comment: $\rho$ is the energy density, not the mass density.

Comment: c = 1, so ρ is used as the mass density. By the way, even if you call it energy density, ρ+3P=0+3(ρ_r/3) does this hold? That is, the energy density of radiation = 0, and only the pressure term exists?

Comment: If you have the Λ/3 in you equation you don't need to use the ρ and P for dark energy, and if you do you don't need the extra Λ/3 term. For the evolution of the different densities see [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/y/) and the links therein.

Comment: Dear Yukterez, You are right about Λ/3 term. By the way, what I'm asking about is the radiation term. I'd love to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

The $\rho$ being used here is in all cases energy density, not mass density, so it's not true that $\rho = 0$ for radiation. It's not about using units with $c=1$; $E = mc^2$ is about rest energy and rest mass, and while radiation has neither, it still has energy. If $p = \rho/3$, then $\rho + 3p$ is simply $2\rho$.

Something that might be confusing is that when talking about matter, we do use $\rho$ to refer to mass density. That's because we're talking about nonrelativistic matter, for which most of its energy is the rest energy, proportional to the mass. Its kinetic energy is negligible, so $\rho \approx \rho_m c^2$. But the $\rho$ appearing in the Friedmann equations is still energy, not mass.

Comment: //The ρ being used here is in all cases energy density, not mass density, so it's not true that ρ=0 for radiation.  If p=ρ/3, then ρ+3p is simply 2ρ.// Are you sure of the above claim?

Comment: In Wikipedia's Friedmann equation(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations), there is an explanatory phrase: ρ and P are the volumetric mass density (and not the volumetric energy density)

Comment: ρ+3P is the source of gravity. If your argument is correct, doesn't it lead to the argument that radiation with energy density ρ exerts a gravitational force of 2ρ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I checked Weinberg's book, which clearly says that $\rho$ is the energy density. The Wikipedia article is confusing at best and wrong at worst. I think they're talking about units: my interpretation is that by "mass density" they just mean "energy density divided by $c^2$".

Comment: And in GR there isn't really a concept of *the* gravitational force exerted by something - and it certainly couldn't be $\rho$ or $2\rho$, which don't have units of force. But it is true that when it comes to radiation, pressure plays a much more important role than it does for matter.